# Log HTTP 500 error on API Call

Tags: php, apache, logging, syntax-error

In /var/log/apache2/error.log I able to trace http 500 error, Only I able to log error when I hit url from browser but when I call api either via ajax call or by postman, then any syntax error(500 error) not logged in apache2/error.log . Please tell me how can I log this one as well. Thx! in advance.

Comment: This is ridiculous, instead of giving answer why you guys doing down vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error and there's nothing wrong with your Apache, then there's probably an issue with your PHP. Look in your PHP error log for an error. If PHP is not logging errors then you need to change the php.ini file so that `log_errors` is `1` and `error_log` is the file name you want errors to be logged to. (I recommend `"error_log"`. This will log all errors to the file error_log in the same directory as the file creating the error.)